# Long load times resulting in app never launching

Tags: gnome

My problem is as follows

I'll go to launch an app (in this case The UbuntuAppStore) I get an icon that looks like a wrist watch it spins for a second and then...nothing. What is happening? This started after I installed hexchat using snap (it failed so I used classic apt-get) any idea what's going on here?

Comment: We don't know your OS & release details, but I'd likely run it from terminal, so messages appear in the terminal itself (and you don't have to look up log files which GUI generally requires).  What messages do you see when started from terminal (and please provide OS & release details).

Comment: Only UbuntuAppStore, or are other apps affected also?